# Changing default environment (default folder) in Canopy on Mac OSX

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, enthought, canopy

I want to change the default environment (the folder where my Canopy files are stored), which I previously set to 'Documents' folder. But now I want to change the folder. If I just delete the folders, Canopy creates them again automatically, indicating that somewhere inside its logs it has saved the default location address, and I want to change this default location address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Quit Canopy
2. Delete the file `~/.canopy/locations.cfg`. You can do this by opening a Terminal window and typing:

   `rm ~/.canopy/locations.cfg`
3. Restart Canopy

You'll be prompted again for your environment path.

Comment: can't find either the folder or the file. I am on Mac OSX 10.9.5

Comment: The lead dot `.` means that it's a hidden folder. Revised answer to show explicitly how to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the root path for the file browser by modifying the variable "root_paths" in the file ./canopy/preferences.ini under the section [file_browser]

Comment: True but IIUC not what the OP was asking.